# Python3 - Objetos dentro de objetos ¿es posible?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, poo

**Estuve mirando unos tutoriales de Js sobre objetos, no sobre POO  y vi que se podian colocar objetos dentro de objetos, les adjunto el código de js:**

```js
const persona= {
  nombre: "pepito",
  contacto:{
     telefono: {
         movistar:{
             fijo: 6465465,
             movil:65464654
         },
         claro: 65464654
     },
     email: "correo@correo.com"
   },
}
print("El telefono movistar fijo es: "+str(persona.contacto.telefono.movistar.fijo))

// Ejecución exitosa
>> El telefono movistar fijo es: 6465465
```

**¿Cuál sería el equivalente en en python?**

Estuve buscando información , pero lo unico que encuentro es sobre POO el código que tengo es así:

```py
class Config:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nameExe = "software.exe" 
        self.debugger = False
        self.other = "other"
    def accion1(self):
        print("se realizó la acción")
```

**Mi duda es si es posible o simplemente python no trabaja así**

Si tienen un foro o un link donde pueda verlo les agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Objetos dentro de objetos en Python**

```py
class Persona:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nombre = "Juanito alimaña :'v "
    class Contacto:
        def __init__(self):
            self.claro = 23423434
        class Movistar:
            def __init__(self):
                self.fijo  = 32434523
                self.movil = 21334243

# Instanciando
p = Persona()
#Mostrando en consola.
print(str(p.Contacto().Movistar().fijo))


---------------------------------------------
>> 32434523
```

Podemos acceder a valores y funciones dentro de los objetos

Answer (score 2):

Sí por supuesto que se puede en Python. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo explicado de dos clases **RandomNumber** que genera un número aleatorio, y **GenerateRandomList** que genera una lista de números aleatorios, utilizando **RandomNumber**:

```
#Creamos una clase que genera un número aleatorio con los parámetros menor y mayor
class RandomNumber():
    def __init__(self, menor, mayor):
        self.nrandom = np.random.randint(menor, mayor)


#Creamos otra clase que genera una lista de números aleatorios con los parámetros menor y mayor.
class GenerateRandomList():

    def __init__(self, menor, mayor):
        self.menor = menor
        self.mayor = mayor
    
    def generate_list(self, n):
        self.random_numbers = []
        for i in range(n):

            #Utilizamos la clase creada previamente que genera un número aleatorio
            random_class = RandomNumber(self.menor, self.mayor)
            self.random_numbers.append(random_class.nrandom)



random_list = GenerateRandomList(50, 100)
random_list.generate_list(15)
random_list.random_numbers
```

Hablando desde mi experiencia personal , solo suelo inicializar objetos dentro de objetos cuando:

- Ahorrarme tiempo modificando clases que ya tenían una funcionalidad que necesitaba
- Cuando creo **Descriptores** (Descriptors en inglés) y tengo que hacer validaciones de datos

Si no suelo resolver problemas como el que yo te he puesto arriba, mediante herencia de clases.

### En resumen

Si todo esto te ha parecido complicado o un rollo. **La respuesta es sí.** Y la mejor manera de recordar que se pueden crear objetos dentro de objetos, es que cualquier pesona que cree un objeto en Python, casí seguro está usando objetos sin que lo sepa.

Cuando usas los simbolos `==` realmente estás creando ese objeto dentro de la clase invocando a la clase `__eq__` que en Python es un método especial. Igual con `>`  que es `__gt__`. También cuando creas strings, los strings realmente son objetos!! Esto lo puedes comprobar con `isinstance("hola qué tal?", str)`

Comment: No era exactamente a lo que me refería, pero me ayudó bastante en abrir mis perspectivas y lo logre hacer.